# Can't change cookie value (php)

Tags: php

I'm setting a cookie like so:

```
setcookie ('myletter', "a", time()+60*60*24*1000, "/", ".me.com" );
```

Then I want to change the value so I do:

```
$_COOKIE['myletter'] = "b"
```

But the old values remains. I also tried using setcookie again, that failed too

```
setcookie ('myletter', "b", time()+60*60*24*1000, "/", ".me.com" );
```

Is there a reliable way I can actually change the value of an existing cookie?

Answer (score 4):

Fire up a tool like Fiddler that lets you see the HTML traffic between your browser and your test web server.  Then look for Set-Cookie: on the response from the PHP script that sets the cookie, and then look for Cookie: in the following request.  The fastest way for you to get it working is to understand cookies in terms of HTTP requests, which is summed up, though not for PHP, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384321(VS.85).aspx) - the concept is the same.